Azure function refuse to run as .NET isolated worker? (Exception: Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.FunctionInputConverterException)
I have an Azure Function in .NET 4.8 (stuck on this framework due to WCF).
The function is trying to receive messages from Azure Servicebus using ServiceBusTrigger.
I get an exception:

Cannot convert input parameter 'message' to type 'Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusReceivedMessage' from type 'System.String'

My assumption is that my function is running "in-process" instead of "isolated" since it tries to map the first argument as a string instead of ServiceBusReceivedMessage - is this correct?
In the exception I can also read:
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.FunctionInputConverterException: Error converting 1 input parameters for Function

It seems to be releated to binding arguments to my Run method invocation.
But I can't understand why it is running in-process then.
In my .csproj I have "Exe"
<TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>

I'm referencing the following packages:
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" Version="7.17.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.18.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.10.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.7.0" />

My host.json looks like this:
{
   "version": "2.0"
}

My deployed function has the following app settings:
{
    "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
    "value": "~4",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
    "value": "dotnet-isolated",
    "slotSetting": false
  }

My implementation is decorated with:
[Function("myspecialfunction")]
public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myspecialqueue", Connection = "<secret>")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message, ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions)

What could possibly be wrong?

There seems to be a bug in Azure Portal when it comes to runtime version and Azure Functions. If I manually create my function in Azure Portal and specify net48 and isolated mode my function is created correctly.
Then I select "Get publish profile" in Azure Portal to download it and import the profile to Visual Studio, then the generated profile.arm.json is inconsitant/corrupt since it specifies:
"FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~3",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
If I now publish my implementation from Visual Studio and inspect the outcome in Azure Portal my function have been converted to an in-process function.
So to makes this work properly I need to correct the corrupted profile.arm.json.


Cannot convert input parameter 'message' to type 'Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusReceivedMessage' from type 'System.String'

You are getting this error because you cannot convert Service bus message to String directly.
To convert from ServiceBusReceivedMessage- to String you need to use .ToString() method.
This worked for me.
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp5
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public async Task Run(
            [ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "SB_conn")]
            ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
            ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Message ID: {id}", message.MessageId);
            _logger.LogInformation("Message Body: {body}", message.Body);
            _logger.LogInformation("Message Content-Type: {contentType}", message.ContentType);

            String stringmessage = message.Body.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine($"Type of stringmessage: {stringmessage.GetType()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Type of message: {message.GetType()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"convert to string message: {stringmessage}");
             

            await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
        }
    }
}


OUTPUT:


I'm already using message.Body.ToString() so that is not my issue.
I don't think its related to my implementation of the Run method. It seems to be a problem when binding input arguments to my Run method:
Exception: Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.FunctionInputConverterException: Error converting 1 input parameters for Function


@FredrikClaesson If you are using in-process model you need to use Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus pcakage.  Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus does not support in in-process model as it is for Isolated process

By using the packages I have specified and having OutputType Exe, FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME dotnet-isolated I was hoping it would run as isolated and not in-process.

@FredrikClaesson you can't use Isolated mode packages and by changing values in local settings after creating in-process model. In isolated model you need to have Program.cs file which defines and declare services.

if you are using .NET 4.8. I would suggest use in-process model. and if your trying use isolated model. you need to use program.cs file.

I have a Program.cs with HostBuilder & ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults. I wouldn't be able to create an Exe type without a Program.cs/Main

@FredrikClaesson can you share your function code
